# ReactStrictMode: useSWR with Axios abortController makes my request canceled

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks, axios, swr

I created a wrapper for useSWR hook to handle abortion on request when my component gets unmounted.
When I'm using my custom hook with the ReactStrictMode on, it just directly cancels my request and does not re-fetch it again.

I think the right behavior would be to not cancel the request to not make the app to fetch two times

Here is a short example of my custom hook :

```
const useRequest = (request: AxiosRequestConfig | null): RequestType => {
  const abort_controller = new AbortController();

  const fetcher = async (
    requestFetcher: AxiosRequestConfig | null
  ): Promise<unknown> => {
    return await axios({
      ...requestFetcher,
      signal: abort_controller.signal,
    })
      .then((response) => {
        return response;
      });
  };

  const {
    data: dataSWR,
    isLoading,
    error
  } = useSWR(
    request && request.method === 'get' ? request.url : null,
    () => fetcher(request),
    {
      revalidateOnFocus: false,
      shouldRetryOnError: false,
    }
  );



  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      if (request !== null) {
        abort_controller.abort();
      }
    };
  }, []);

  return {
    loading: isLoading,
    status: dataSWR ? dataSWR?.status : 0,
    headers: dataSWR ? dataSWR?.headers : null,
    data: dataSWR ? dataSWR?.data.result : null,
    error: error,
  };
};
```

I'm using this custom hook like this :

```
const request = useRequest({
    url: '/api/invitations',
    method: 'get',
  });
```

Comment: maybe it's just us two, but I also find this confusing that second re-render by StrictMode does not send a request again. So I filed https://github.com/vercel/swr/issues/2766 - let's see what community answers.

Comment: Okay nice, seems to be the same problem. Let's see then!

Comment: can you comment there with real-life scenario? The team closed my over-simplified case as "I don't see any reason to do that"

Comment: I commented on it @skyboyer